# How to import html file in typescript?

Tags: html, typescript, import

Is there any way to import HTML file in typescript by not using require.
import abc from '../templates/abc.html'; -- This is not loading my html

Answer (score 0):

import * as template from "template.html";

@Component({

selector: 'home',

directives: [RouterLink],

template: template
})

Comment: I am not using angular, my application is typescript and jquery package.